# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'storagedTechs.split')

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

**I'm getting the following error: Possible unhandled promise rejection (id:0: Network request failed)** sometimes the error id change for id:3. can anybody help me?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Image, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

import SpotList from '../components/SpotList';

import logo from '../assets/logo.png';

export default function List () {

    const [techs, setTechs] = useState ([]);
   

    useEffect(() => {
        AsyncStorage.getItem('techs')
            .then((storagedTechs) => {
                const techsArray = storagedTechs.split(',').map(tech => tech.trim())

                setTechs(techsArray)
            })
    },[]);


    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
            <Image style={styles.logo} source={logo}/>

            {techs.map(tech => <SpotList key={tech} tech={tech}/>)}
        </SafeAreaView>
    )
 }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        
    },
    logo: {
        height: 32,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
        alignSelf:'center',
        marginTop: 50
    },
})
```

[error in expo go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U7Q0.jpg)

Comment: Were is `storagedTechs` set - if its null you wil get this error

Answer (score 0):

I would have tried adding catch block after then block, like

```js
.then((storagedTechs) => {
    const techsArray = storagedTechs.split(',').map(tech => tech.trim())

    setTechs(techsArray)
})
.catch(err => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
});
```

This will help you in further debugging.